# if condition is becoming true even though the values are not equal

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] num=new int[] {1, 5, 0,2, 2, -3, 1, 10};
    Sample.getSocks(num);
  }


public static void getSocks(int[] integers) {
int[] c=new int[integers.length];
int a=0;
    for(int i=0;i<integers.length;i++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int k=0;k<c.length;k++)
        {
            if(integers[i]==(c[k]))
            {
                count=1;
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("value"+integers[i]);
        System.out.println(count);
            if(count!=1)
            {
                c[a]=integers[i];
                a++;
            }

        }

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(c));
}
```

output for the above code is : [1, 5, 2, -3, 10, 0, 0, 0]

actual output i want is : [1, 5, 0, 2, -3, 10, 0, 0]

While comparing the value 0 with the values of integer array C,if condition (if(0==1)) is becoming true every time.

Can anyone please explain why the if condition is becoming true even though the values are not equal?

Comment: You're looking at this the wrong way. You should be asking what is wrong with your code (the values are obviously not what you think they are) rather than suggesting java itself is not working properly. Step through your code and see for yourself.

Comment: Use a debugger, so sick of seeing these "debug my code for me it doesnt work" questions

Comment: It's not clear what this code is supposed to do (eliminate duplicates?), but the reason the 0 at the 3 position is not copied to the output array is clear - the output array already contains 0s (it contains all 0s by default when it is instantiated), so `if(integers[i]==(c[k]))` is true for at least one value of `k`.

Comment: Your code says, "Copy the value from the old array to the new one if they are not the same value." Because `0 == 0`, the third value is never copied because it is the same in both arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `c` began filled with zeros

You should use:

```
    for(int k=0;k<a;k++)
    {
        if(integers[i]==(c[k]))
        {
            count=1;
        }   
    }
```

instead:

```
    for(int k=0;k<c.length;k++)
    {
        if(integers[i]==(c[k]))
        {
            count=1;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array `c` it's empty trying this it's gives the same reuslt every time:

```
   if(integers[i]==(c[k]))
```

Because you have always `c[k] = 0`

Comment: probably because you are always either answering these terrible questions, or just straight up code dumping answers... and I'm not the one who downvoted you FYI. It only encourages more of the same crap

Comment: @redFIVE the reasons you just described are no reason to downvote - http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that its the reason its getting downvoted. Repwh*ring on questions like this makes people think its ok to ask garbage like this question

Answer (score 0):

Integer arrays initialize as all zeros. You're getting the incorrect output because when you get to `integers[2]==(c[k])`, you are comparing 0 to 0 (which is `true`) and setting count to 1, so your code tells you that 0 already exists and doesn't add it to the list